# Trying "Messaging via attribute" from the documentation

Tags: catel

I'm trying to get the hung of catel but have a problem.
Trying "Messaging via attribute" gets an compile error.

> 'Catel.MVVM.ViewModelBase.GetService(object)' is obsolete: 'GetService is no longer >recommended. It is better to inject all dependencies (which the TypeFactory fully supports) >Will be removed in version 4.0.0.'

```
    private void OnCmdExecute()
    {
      var mediator = GetService<IMessageMediator>();
      mediator.SendMessage("Test Value");
    }

    [MessageRecipient]
    private void ShowMessage(string value)
    {
      var messageService = GetService<IMessageService>();
      messageService.Show(value);
    }
```

I'm using 3.9.
A hint and a code snippet whould be good help.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetService is marked obsolete. You have 2 options:

1) If you are using a view model, simply let the services be injected in the constructor:

```
private readonly IMessageMediator _messageMediator;
private readonly IMessageService _messageService;

public MyViewModel(IMessageMediator messageMediator, IMessageService messageService)
{
    Argument.IsNotNull(() => messageMediator);
    Argument.IsNotNull(() => messageService);

    _messageMediator = messageMediator;
    _messageService= messageService;
}
```

2) Use the GetDependencyResolver extension method:

```
var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
var messageMediator = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IMessageMediator>();
```

Solution 1 is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. 
I also found a good example in the "Catel.Examples" solution, [link to download](https://github.com/Catel/Catel.Examples/tree/45654f24839bf93c292463817b961ae16509e0b2)